# How can I change the change Jasper Reports PDF version during runtime

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How do I set the export pdf version at run time in Jasper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your instance of `JRPdfExporter`, call the method `setParameter` and use the constants defined in `JRPdfExporterParameter` to set the version appropriately.

Example:

`exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_VERSION, JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_VERSION_1_2);`

There are constants for versions 1.2 through 1.7.

For your code, the solution would be something like this:

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, con);
File outputFile = new File("[Your destination filename goes here]"); 
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, outputFile);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_VERSION, JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_VERSION_1_2);
exporter.exportReport();
```

The pdf will then be written to `outputFile`, so you won't need to call `printReport`.

Comment: my code is as below:    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
     param, con);

   printReport(data, request, print); After this i have to create object for exporter and set the parameter?

Comment: @Karthick I've updated my answer with a specific code example. Hope that helps.

Comment: Pls help on below link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269631/unwanted-helvetica-font-is-using-in-pdf-by-jasper . thanks much.