# Unwanted Helvetica font is using in pdf by Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem that Helvetica, which I am not using in any of my JRXML fields, is being used as the default font in Jasper PDF reports.

I am using iReports 4.0.2.

Answer (score 6):

- The first variant is to set the default font via setting **`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name`** and/or **`net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name`** properties.

For example, it were my defaults settings in *iReport* (dialog *Options -> JasperReports Properties*):

[image: default settings]

With this settings (without setting default style in the template) I have the **Helvetica** font in my *pdf* generated by *iReport*.

After that I've changed settings in *iReport* like this:

[image: set another font]

And now I have **Courier** font in my *pdf* file (generated by *iReport*):

[image: pdf]

With *JasperReports API* you can set this properties with help of [JRProperties.setProperty(java.lang.String key, boolean value)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRProperties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) method.

The sample:

```java
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name", defaultPDFFont);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
```

- Another variant is to add default style in report's template.

The example:

```xml
<jasperReport .. topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Base" isDefault="true" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" fontSize="10" pdfFontName="Courier" pdfEncoding="UTF8" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <queryString>
```

---

More information about working with fonts you can read [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fonts).

Comment: we hvae set the properties as below: net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=SansSerif net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.size=10 net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=HeiseiMin-W3 net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1252 net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=true net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=false But still, helvetica is appearing in file properties -> fonts tab. But we never used the font anywhere in the template. Pls help on this.

Comment: Can you search over jrxml file the phrase "Helvetica". What is a result?

Comment: 'Helvetica' not found. Also theres comment in a link http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=74379 => "As long as you have a default style in the report that uses a font extension, the hidden page anchors will use it and no Helvetica will end up in the resulting PDF." i cant able to u'stand it, can you pls explain me?

Comment: The link that you provided told that it was a bug of an old iReport version. You can set default font in template

Comment: im exporting the pdf through API. in ireport i am using isPdfFont, isPdfEncoding, isEmbedded font options. But is there defaultPdfFont option in 4.0.3 version?

Comment: thanks much for your time. I want to know the difference between the report font and pdf font. When we are generatin report in PDF, is it necessary to mention report font? If so we need to mention, below is my scenarion: Report font - MS Mincho, pdf font: HeiseiMin-W3. I have to print it. Printing company wants the font with subset. I don't want to embed the default "helvetica" font in the report (which increases the file size huge). So i want to remove using the default font itself. Any suggestions how to stop calling the default font?

Comment: For your case (HeiseiMin-W3 using) it will be better to use font extension. For more info you can read my answer for this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268096/difference-between-ireports-internal-preview-pdf-preview/8268632#8268632

Comment: yes. but for this font extension option, we need heiseimin.ttf file? but i couldn't able to find heiseimin.ttf file.

Comment: also, i would like to ask, in ur above screen shot i could able to see only one font in the properties. I believe u set pdf font as "Courier". Is it possible to leave reportfont unselected? because in ur properties, only "Courier" is shown. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand - you are going to use `HeiseiMin-W3` without having this font (ttf files)? You question was how to avoid `Helvetica` appearance in the pdf file. What is your new question?

Comment: The font should be in your classpath, otherwise you will get the exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : pdfFontName : HeiseiMin-W3 pdfEncoding : UTF-8 isPdfEmbedded : false at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:1941‌​) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.writePageAnchor(JRPdfExporter.j‌​ava:690)

Comment: sorry for the confusion. By default it takes helvetica. but i could able to change this to Heiseimin using Style. The problem is two font types (report font and PDF font) are displaying in PDF properties.

Comment: Apart from these two, I could able to embed report font using extension as JAR. But im not able to embed this pdf font (Heiseimin). I want report either to do not use pdf font or need to be embedded. Please suggest if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to make a hack - to create `HeiseiMin-W3` font extension (jar file) without having ttf files for this font (I've used another ttf files). But my attempt was failed - the itext library raised exception for my "hacked" font jar file. I think that it is impossiblie to use `pdf font` without having `ttf` files. For a report font (`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name`) you can add any nonexistent font, in this case you should set `net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font` propery as `true`. You should find this ttf font, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I use NetBeans and on one of my projects i wanted to use Garamond as my default font for my pdfs so what i did was:

1. Tools -> options
2. Under IReport, click the Fonts Tab
3. Install a Font
4. Click on the "Export as Extension Button" which exports it as a jar file.
5. Add to class path.

Run report, save it, then view it.